# How can a SAP BO publication fail when it formerly worked fine, while the publication didn't change?

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a WebI report that I sent via a scheduled publication, this is done for months already, and it used to work fine until last week.

Some of my dynamic recipients get only half the information, others dont get information at all. The publication has the status succes, and when I look into the log file, I don't see any differences from the publication that worked fine before. When generating the report there are no issues as well, and the report wasn't changed since the end of June. The publication didn't change since the start of October. The publication only has dynamic recipients, which are requested via a WebI report that uses a handwritten SQL query.

I am using an oracle database to get the dynamic recipients, and I am using a SQL Server database via an ODBC connection in order to generate the actual report.

I already tried to recreate the publication, but the same problems occur. Does anyone have an idea of what I could try?

Comment: I don't use publications so I cannot help you. You might find more help on [SAP Q&A](https://answers.sap.com/index.html) (SAP login required) or the [BusinessObjects Board](https://bobj-board.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already used SAP Q&A, but they were not able to give me an answer. I will try BOB too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that if your reports get big, memory is exceeded, and therefore reports are cut off in the end. Making sure the queries of the generated reports request less data solved the problem.